# What are the common reasons for slow down of games made with phaser for 2-3 seconds in the middle of game play?

Tags: phaser-framework

I wrote a game for desktop using phaser, i had followed all their guidelines regarding memory free & object destruction after completion of a state but i can't understand why the game is giving jerks for 2-3 seconds each time during the entire game play(especially the tile sprite), i want to know what might be the other reasons?

Comment: This question seems too broad for SO format.

Answer (score 8):

from my Experience there are few things i noticed that it makes phaser game slow specially on mobile devices .

tileSprit : as you mention it is very slow and to be honest i don't know why but i create a blank game and tested it FPS = 60 , then i draw tile sprite simple tile

```
game.add.tileSprite(0,0,worldWidth , worldHeight , key);
```

FPS = 30 !

so i replaced it with one big sprite and tested it FPS = 45 to 50 ! it is ok i can live with that .

bitmap font : is also heavy don't use it a lot

loop inside update function is also drop the fps .

p2 physic : calling a lot of collide function and a lot of bodies (destroy the physic body as son as you done with it )

particle system : simple particle also Reduce the FPS more than 10

phaser is nice and easy but performance part need a lot of work .

EDIT

i tested Pixi for tile sprite and it is fast like Leopard FPS = 60 and sometimes more than that i will recommend using pixi tile sprite .

Comment: what you said is absolutely 100% correct regarding phaser performance regarding `tile sprite` & i too believe that rich needs to improve it (especially tile sprite rendering a lot!!), i never even dreamt of using phaser for mobile (you know why ;) ), but all in all i don't have p2physics, bitmap font or particle system in my game yet!! the annoying hicups due to `tilesprite` , and offcourse i must say phaser is great!! regarding it's simplicity & availability of great community to help out!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Profile it using Chrome and see. If it's a function, that will show it. If it's lagging while rendering, it will show spikes during paint operations. It could be anything though - garbage collection, audio decoding (a common hidden frame rate killer), things you thought were destroyed but weren't really, excessive texture loads on the GPU and so on.

Comment: from what i've experienced the only thing that annoying me is the tilesprite rendering performance, can we expect a better performance in coming update ? & one more thing, phaser failure rate is more regarding looping audio, all of a sudden the audio stops completely & restarts after 2-3 minutes, hence for now i am using howler.js for audio stuff & it's great!!